# How to plot this in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, figure

I have following code

```
xr=randi([1 150],1,20)
    z=numel(xr);
    N=10;  %Window length
    gAll=zeros(1,z-N+1);
    for n=0:z-N;
        x=xr(1+n:N+n)
      d=max(x);
        m=numel(x);
        y=zeros(d,1);
        p=zeros(d,d);
        for k=1:m-1
        y(x(k))=y(x(k))+1; 
        p(x(k),x(k+1))=p(x(k),x(k+1))+1;
        end
        p=bsxfun(@rdivide,p,y);
        p(isnan(p)) = 0; 
        j=prod(p(p~=0));
        [~,~,idx] = unique(x);
        q=prod(hist(idx,1:max(idx))/numel(x));
        s=log(j);
        l=log(q);
        g=s+l
    gAll(n+1)=g;
    end
    plot(gAll)
```

I want a plot such a that for threshold line of gAll =-22, graph above threshold line should be in red color and  graph below threshold line should in blue, but graph should in continuous joint with these two different colors, how to do it.

Comment: Instead of `y(x(k))=y(x(k))+1` in the loop, call `tabulate (x)` (before the loop) and then take the second column.

Answer (score 0):

You can mask areas of the graph by setting values to `NaN`. I would create a high resolution interpolant of the data `gAll`, then create two coppies, ones with `gAll>-22` masked and one with `gAll<-22` masked and plot them on the same axes.

You could make `gAll_HR` a high resolution version of your vector `gAll` on `x_HR` with `interp1(x, gAll, x_HR)`, then replace values with `NaN` using logical indexing:

```
gAll_low = gAll_HR;
gAll_low(gAll_HR>=-22) = NaN;
gAll_high = gAll_HR;
gAll_high(gAll_HR<-22) = NaN;

plot(x_HR, gAll_low, 'b-', x_HR, gAll_high, 'r-')
```

Comment: I am not understand, can u post whole code so that I can directly run it.

Comment: @RamShivshankar just write:
`x_HR = 1:0.01:max(x);` (instead of `0.01` you can choose whatever resolution you want, try and see the difference)
then `gAll_HR = interp1(x,gAll,x_HR);`
then copy the code from above, and it will work.
If you run it no small vectors like in the examples you may get the error _The grid vectors are not strictly monotonic increasing._, though I don't know what it means...